# autofac violation of generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am getting this error in my asp.net web api project which I suspect is due to some mistake I must have made when configuring my container:

> GenericArguments[0], 'Model.AppUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[TUser,TKey]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.

This is how I register this type on my startup.cs file:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserStore<AppUser>>().As<IUserStore<AppUser, Guid>>().InstancePerRequest();
```

And here are my classes:

```
 public class AppUser : ModelBase, IUser<Guid>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

    // other fields omitted for brevity ...


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AppUser, Guid> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, this.Email));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.FirstName))
        {
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, this.FirstName));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.LastName))
        {
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, this.LastName));
        }
        return userIdentity;
    }
}


   public class UserStore<TUser> : IUserLoginStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserClaimStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserPasswordStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserEmailStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserLockoutStore<TUser, Guid>,
                                IUserStore<TUser, Guid>
       where TUser : AppUser
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;
    private readonly IUserClaimRepository _userClaimRepo;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<AppUserLogin, Guid> _userLoginRepo;

    public UserStore(IUserRepository userRepo, IUserClaimRepository userClaimRepo,
                     IGenericRepository<AppUserLogin, Guid> userLoginRepo)
    {
        _userRepo = userRepo;
        _userClaimRepo = userClaimRepo;
        _userLoginRepo = userLoginRepo;
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        _userRepo.Add(user);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    // other methods omitted for brevity
  }
```

The funny thing is that the way I register my type works perfectly in a asp.net MVC project, but not in a web api one. The reason I am getting this error now is that I've decided to move all my security concerns (i.e. log in, log out, registration, etc.) to my web api layer.

A Google search hasn't helped much so far. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1 09/04 12:30 PM GMT - Added stack trace**

> Server Error in '/' Application. GenericArguments[0],
>   'Model.AppUser', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[TUser,TKey]' violates the
>   constraint of type parameter 'TUser'. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0],
>   'Model.AppUser', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[TUser,TKey]' violates the
>   constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0],
>   'Model.AppUser', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[TUser,TKey]' violates the
>   constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr*
>   pInst, Int32 numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst) +94
>   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation) +209
>
> [ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0],
>   'Model.AppUser', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[TUser,TKey]' violates the
>   constraint of type 'TUser'.]
>
>   System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition,
>   RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e) +4182003
>
>   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation) +225
>
>   Autofac.Features.Variance.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__2(Type[]
>   a) +13    System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +157 
>   System.Linq.d__14`2.MoveNext() +393
>
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +81
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.GetInitializedServiceInfo(Service
>   service) +268
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(Service
>   service) +87
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.d__a.MoveNext() +301
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.GetInitializedServiceInfo(Service
>   service) +268
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration(Service
>   service, IComponentRegistration& registration) +82
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.CanSupplyValue(ParameterInfo
>   pi, IComponentContext context, Func`1& valueProvider) +124
>
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding..ctor(ConstructorInfo
>   ci, IEnumerable`1 availableParameters, IComponentContext context) +213
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4(ConstructorInfo
>   ci) +34    System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
>
>   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +85
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +132
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
>
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +154
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters) +48
>
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.<Execute>b__0() +7
>
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id,
>   Func`1 creator) +120
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +132
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
>
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IComponentContext
>   c, IEnumerable`1 p) +19
>
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters) +48    Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
>
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0()
>   +31    Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
>   +94    Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +185
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters) +48    Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
>
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext
>   c, IEnumerable`1 p) +19
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
>
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters) +48    Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
>
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +44
>
> [DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while
>   executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details.
>   ---> GenericArguments[0], 'Model.AppUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[TUser,TKey]' violates the
>   constraint of type 'TUser'. (See inner exception for details.)]
>
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +112
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +109
>
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
>   +74    Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +53
>   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
>   serviceType) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +41
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'UI.Controllers.AccountController'. Make
>   sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +77
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +88
>   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IControllerFactory_CreateController.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
>   +118    Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +80    Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed()
>   +11    Glimpse.Core.Extensions.AlternateMethodContextExtensions.TryProceedWithTimer(IAlternateMethodContext
>   context, TimerResult& timerResult) +41
>   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext
>   context) +25
>   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation
>   invocation) +84    Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>   +108    Castle.Proxies.IControllerFactoryProxy.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +214
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +191    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: could you share your `Model.AppUser` and `UserStore<T>` class definition ?

Comment: sure, will edit my question

Comment: unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce the issue with your concrete types :( Could you add the stack trace of the error ?

Comment: I finally found what the issue was. This line was breaking my code: builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource()); The reason I am using this is because I use mediatr (https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR). I have now to do more digging to find out why this is happening since it wasn't before ...

Comment: @afgallo did you find your issue? I am running into the same thing.

Comment: @cangerer see my comment above. I simply removed the contravariant registration and it all worked fine. Apparently there isn't a need to resister that with autofac.

Comment: Note that some of your MediatR handlers might stop working when you do not use ContravariantRegistrationSource

Comment: Tried with and without ContravariantRegistrationSource, in both cases the problem for me. Does anyone have any other solutions?